# Спойлер с меняющимися маркерами

Tags: javascript, jquery, marker

Мне нужно сделать блок спойлеров, которые открываются по клику (с этим проблем нет, код ниже). При этом по клику иконка спойлера должна меняться с "+" на "-", а заголовок активного спойлера должен становиться жирным. после клика на другой спойлер открытый ранее спойлер должен закрываться и менять свой значок обратно на "+".
в коде ниже  "+" на "-" меняется, но для всех спойлеров и навсегда(
Я новичок в JS и не могу понять как это делать. помогите плиз :)

Демо на JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a5py9z9v/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

//SPOILERS  
var icon = $('.spoiler_links');
    icon.find('span').text('+');
 $('.spoiler_links').click(function()
  {
    $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_body').toggle('fast');
    var icon = $('.spoiler_links');
    icon.find('span').text('-'); 
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.spoiler_body {
 display:none;
 }
 .spoiler_links {
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#5f6a70;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  font-size:1em;
  }
.spoiler_body {
 font-size:0.9em;
}
.spoilerblock {
 padding:1% 0;
 border-bottom:1px solid #dddede;
}
.icon {
 font-size:1.8em;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#51758c;
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
 position:relative;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="spoilers">
    <div class="spoilerblock">
        <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler1 <span class="icon"></span></a>
            <div class="spoiler_body">
                   <p>
                   content
                   </p>
            </div>
     </div>
     <div class="spoilerblock">
        <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler2 <span class="icon"></span></a>
            <div class="spoiler_body">
                   <p>
                   content
                   </p>
            </div>
     </div>
     <div class="spoilerblock">
        <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler3 <span class="icon"></span></a>
            <div class="spoiler_body">
                   <p>
                   content
                   </p>
            </div>
     </div>       
     
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Демо 1: http://jsfiddle.net/7qe0tj2u/

```js
var icon = $('.spoiler_links');
icon.find('span').text('+');

$('.spoiler_links').click(function() {
  //сначала закроем все другие спойлеры
  var $other_spoilers = $('a.spoiler_links').not(this);
  $other_spoilers.siblings().hide('fast');
  //и заодно вернем им плюсики
  $other_spoilers.find('span').text('+');
  // теперь собственно откроем кликнутый спойлер
  // кстати, сын моего отца - мой брат ;) по-английски - сиблинг
  //  $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_body').toggle('fast');   
  $(this).siblings().show('fast')

  // фикс для минусов
  // старый код выбирает ВСЕ спойлеры на странице, а нам нужен только кликнутый, правда?
  //var icon = $('.spoiler_links');
  //  icon.find('span').text('-'); 

  $(this).find('span').text('-');

  return false;
});
```

```css
.spoiler_body {
  display: none;
}
.spoiler_links {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #5f6a70;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.spoiler_body {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.spoilerblock {
  padding: 1% 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddede;
}
.icon {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #51758c;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spoilers">
  <div class="spoilerblock">
    <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler1 <span class="icon"></span></a>
    <div class="spoiler_body">
      <p>
        content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerblock">
    <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler2 <span class="icon"></span></a>
    <div class="spoiler_body">
      <p>
        content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerblock">
    <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler3 <span class="icon"></span></a>
    <div class="spoiler_body">
      <p>
        content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Вторая версия, где открытый спойлер открывается и закрывается:

```js
var icon = $('.spoiler_links');
icon.find('span').text('+');

$('.spoiler_links').click(function() {
  //сначала закроем все другие спойлеры
  var $other_spoilers = $('a.spoiler_links').not(this);
  $other_spoilers.siblings().hide('fast');
  //и заодно вернем им плюсики
  $other_spoilers.find('span').text('+');
  // раньше мы открывали кликнутый спойлер  
  //$(this).siblings().show('fast')
  // а теперь мы его переключаем - toggle
  // но теперь нам придется-таки проверить, закрылся он или открылся
  // чтобы поставить ему "-" или "+" по окончании анимации
  $(this).siblings().toggle('fast', function() {

    var $icon = $(this).siblings('a.spoiler_links').find('span')
    if ($icon.text() == '+') {
      $icon.text('-')
    } else {
      $icon.text('+')
    }

  })

  return false;
});
```

```css
.spoiler_body {
  display: none;
}
.spoiler_links {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #5f6a70;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.spoiler_body {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.spoilerblock {
  padding: 1% 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddede;
}
.icon {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #51758c;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spoilers">
  <div class="spoilerblock">
    <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler1 <span class="icon"></span></a>
    <div class="spoiler_body">
      <p>
        content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerblock">
    <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler2 <span class="icon"></span></a>
    <div class="spoiler_body">
      <p>
        content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerblock">
    <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler3 <span class="icon"></span></a>
    <div class="spoiler_body">
      <p>
        content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wrhqc34c/

Comment: Очень спасибо за помощь и ЧПК (человеко понятные комменты)!
А можете еще подсказать как сделать, чтобы открытый спойлер можно было по клику закрыть?
в изначальном коде это не нужно было дополнительно прописывать, сейчас, видимо необходимо.

Comment: Добавил вторую версию. Первую не убирал для сравнения и обучения.

Comment: Большое спасибо! то что нужно, и хороший плюс к моим скромным познаниям :)